# Tengo inconvenientes con algunos estilos de mi CSS al instalar Bootstrap en Angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy aprendiendo y no he logrado encontrar solución a mi problema. Estoy utilizando Bootstrap en su ultima versión en mi proyecto de Angular, pero he tenido algunos problemas con los estilos que ya tenia definidos en mi style.css.

Uno de ellos es el grosor y tamaño de la fuente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y otro de mis problemas es con el diseño de la barra de los skills que no se cargaron completamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi **`intex.html`**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Selene Chavez -- Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!--Box Icons-->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <!--Box Icons-->
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Mis estilos CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Mi estilo en CSS:

```
/* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 2rem;
}

/* Variables */
:root {
    --main-color: #F24822;
    --body-color: #090a1a;
    --container-color: #171b3c;
    --heading-color: #222231;
    --box-color: #0d0f26;
    --bg-color: #fff;
}

body {
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--body-color);
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5rem;
    background: transparent;
}


html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--heading-color)
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    padding: 3rem 0 2rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.header-active {
    background: var(--box-color);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.navbar-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90px;
}

.navbar-logo img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 0.94rem;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
    background: var(--container-color);
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Menu Icon */
.menu-icon {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    row-gap: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 200;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu-icon div {
    display: block;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    height: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.move .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.move .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.move .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.home {
    min-height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 7rem;
}

.home-content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.home-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fd7051;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.home-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-text h3 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h3::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: -15px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h3::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    right: -35px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 4.8rem;
}

.home-text p {
    font-size: 0.938rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.home-text .color {
    color: var(--main-color);

}

.social {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.social .bx {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--container-color);
}

.social .bx:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Heading */
.heading {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--heading-color);
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.about-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.about-data span {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.about-data h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 0.97rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--main-color);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.btn .bx {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.about-text p {
    font-size: 0.938rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

/* Skills */
.skills {
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

.skills .content-section {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.skills .row {
    display: flex;
}

.skills .row .col {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.skills .row .col h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.skills .skill>span {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.skills .skill .skills-bar {
    height: 8px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: var(--heading-color);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.skills .skill .progress {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8px;
}

.skills .skill .skills-bar span {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -17px;
    right: -15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.skills .skill .javascript {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s javascript forwards;
}

@keyframes javascript {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 75%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .htmlcss {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s htmlcss forwards;
}

@keyframes htmlcss {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 89%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .python {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s python forwards;
}

@keyframes python {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 85%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .mysql {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s mysql forwards;
}

@keyframes mysql {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .photoshop {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s photoshop forwards;
}

@keyframes photoshop {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .comunicacion {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s comunicacion forwards;
}

@keyframes comunicacion {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .trabajoequipo {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s trabajoequipo forwards;
}

@keyframes trabajoequipo {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 75%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .creatividad {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s creatividad forwards;
}

@keyframes creatividad {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .autodidacta {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s autodidacta forwards;
}

@keyframes autodidacta {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 95%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .productividad {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s productividad forwards;
}

@keyframes productividad {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

/* Curriculum */
.estudios {
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

.estudios .content-section {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.estudios .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.estudios .row .col {
    width: 49%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.estudios .row .col h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.estudios .row .left {
    border-right: 2px solid var(--container-color);
}

.estudios .row .right {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--container-color);
}

.estudios .row .item {
    padding: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: var(--heading-color);
    position: relative;
}

.estudios .row .item h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.estudios .row .item .institucion {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

.estudios .row .item .fecha {
    display: block;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.estudios .row .item p {
    line-height: 24px;
}

.estudios .row .left {
    border-right: 2px solid var(--heading-color);
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.estudios .row .right {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--heading-color);
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectori {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -47px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectori .circlei {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectord {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -47px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectord .circled {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

/* Portfolio */
.portfolio-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
}

.portfolio-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.portfolio-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(59, 40, 22, 0.7);
}

.portfolio-overlay h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.portfolio-overlay .bx {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--bg-color);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.portfolio-overlay .bx:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-overlay {
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

/* Contact Form */
.contact-form {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 1rem;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 15px;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--box-color);
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}

.contact-form .send-btn {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-form .send-btn:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 1.4rem;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.footer p {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

/* Scroll Top */
.scroll-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    right: 1.5rem;
}

.scroll-top .bx {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--box-color);
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.scroll-top .bx:hover {
    background: var(--container-color);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.scroll-active {
    bottom: 2rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Responsive */
@media (max-width:990px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:892px) {
    section {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }

    .nav {
        padding: 12px 0;
    }

    .heading {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 257px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:775px) {
    .nav {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .logo {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }

    .home {
        min-height: 500px;
        padding-top: 6rem;
    }

    .home-text h3 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .home-text h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3.8rem;
    }

    .home-text p {
        font-size: 0.825rem;
    }

    .skills {
        padding: 10px 50px;
    }

    .skills .row .col h3 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .estudios .content-section {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 245px;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: var(--box-color);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px 20px;
        transition: 0.5s all cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    }

    .open-menu {
        right: 0;
        transition: 0.5s all cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    }

    .nav-link {
        display: block;
        margin: 1rem 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width:635px) {
    .about-content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .about-data span {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .about-data h2 {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        line-height: 2.3rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 0.8rem 0;
    }

    .about-text p {
        font-size: 0.825rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
    }

    .estudios .row {
        display: block;
    }

    .estudios .row .col {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .estudios .row .right {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:450px) {
    .home {
        min-height: 485px;
        padding-top: 5rem;
    }

    .home-img {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .home-img img {
        width: 120px;
        height: 160px;
    }

    .home-text h2 {
        font-size: 2.1rem;
        line-height: 3.2rem;
    }

    .home-text p br {
        display: contents;
    }

    .heading {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .about-data h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 2.1rem;
        margin: 0.6rem 0;
    }

    .skills .row {
        display: block;
    }

    .skills .row .col {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .skills .row .col .skills-bar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio-content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media (max-width:325px) {
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 190px;
    }
}
```

Las rutas en el Test de `**Angular.json`**:

```
    "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Y por ultimo, dejo parte de la estructura de los ficheros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues si usas clases con los mismos nombres que bootstrap, unas van a machacar a las otras siempre. Si no usas los mismos nombres de clase, nadie te impide tener importados dos, cinco o cien archivos de estilos. Simplemente añádelo en tu html y listo.

Comment: Lo tengo dentro del HTML, pero no logro que me lea mi estilo CSS.

Comment: Sin ver lo que estás haciendo es imposible ayudarte. Como ya te he dicho, nada impide tener múltiples hojas de estilos a la vez, incluso con Bootstrap de por medio, ergo, algo has tenido que hacer mal o algún error tiene que haber, si no estaría funcionando como debe! Pero si no podemos ver cómo añades los CSS y cómo es tu proyecto... cómo pretendes que podamos ayudarte? No somos adivinos.

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta, con todo lo necesario, es que es la primera vez que utilizo esta pagina y estoy aprendiendo todavía. 

Comment: Intento ayudar pero no veo nada claro. Puedes agregar al menos el código HTML donde se aprecie como estás generando el texto que adjuntaste (**ABOUT**).

Comment: Gracias, ya pude solucionar mi inconveniente. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUALIZACION**

Pude solucionar mi inconveniente de la siguiente forma:

1- Como estaba utilizando el paquete Bootstrap npm, saque el enlace cdn bootstrap en index.html.

2- En angular.json, hay que incluir tanto bootstrap css como js, en el objeto del servidor también para usarlo mientras crea la build.

3- Para anular el problema de estilo en algunas situaciones, se puede utilizar !importante en style.css donde se observe que el estilo está por encima de las clases de bootstrap.

Comment: En cuanto a `!important`, no está demás conocer sus reglas, relacionadas a [_especificidad_](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#la_excepci%C3%B3n_!important).

Answer (score 0):

para que no te modifique todos los estilos, tambien puedes hacer las importaciones del bootstrap en un componente especifico por medio de una clase, asi no se alteran los estilos de los demas archivos (al estar embebido en los estilos generales "styles.css"), esto en los casos donde solo tengas que usar componentes en partes especificas de tu sistema

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).